# Have an empty docs in querySnaphsot when trying to get data with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I recently developped a firebase schedule function to retrieve data on every monday.
I tested it during the previous days and it was working correctly. However, this morning, I discovered that my query wasn't able anymore to retrieve data as it used to do. I now have an empty array at QuerySnapshot.docs. You can find my code below:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * 1").onRun(async () => {
  console.log("start");
  const querySnapshotnext = await db.collection("Next_challenges").orderBy("createdAt").get();

  console.log("Let see querySnapshot :", querySnapshotnext); //it works, I can see QuerySnapshot object
  console.log("Let see docs :", querySnapshotnext.docs); //have an empty array [] even if it should not, it wasn't empty few days ago
  console.log("let see the data of the first doc : ", querySnapshotnext.docs[0].data()); //is of course undefined
  
  return null;
});
```

You can find my database below with the doc that is normally selected:

[image]

The rules of my databases are the following :

[image]

I don't really understand why my code isn't working anymore, I think it's certainly related to some parameters stuffs and don't really know how I could debug this by myself so don't hesitate to give me some tips so I can be more autonomous with firebase. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) has a note that says,

> An orderBy() clause also filters for existence of the given field. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given field.

You have `.orderBy("createdAt")` in your query but there isn't any `createdAt` field in the documents (at least the one in screenshot). Did you change your document structure recently that is causing this issue?

---

Also the Admin SDK bypasses any security rules so I'd recommend setting them to false if you don't need to access data directly from client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was the problem. "createdAt" used to be a field in my documents but I actually thought that createdAt was an inherent field in docs then I decided to delete it. It is now working correctly as it used to be. I still don't really understand what did I miss while testing my function the other days. Thank you again !